# How to disable Emacs auto moving command to right?

Tags: emacs, formatting, comments

I'm using the most recent version of Emacs on Windows 7. Let's say I type the following code in my `.emacs`:

```
;test|
```

`|` means the cursor position. Now if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the text will be moved to the right and it will look like:

```
                                                      ;test
```

How to disable this feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is done in accordance with the [Emacs Lisp style guide](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Comment-Tips.html):

> Comments that start with a single semicolon, '`;`', should all be aligned to the same column on the right of the source code. Such comments usually explain how the code on that line does its job. For example:
>
> ```
> (setq base-version-list                 ; There was a base
>       (assoc (substring fn 0 start-vn)  ; version to which
>              file-version-assoc-list))  ; this looks like
>                                         ; a subversion.
> ```

If you use two or more semicolons you will see other behaviour:

> Comments that start with two semicolons, '`;;`', should be aligned to the same level of indentation as the code. Such comments usually describe the purpose of the following lines or the state of the program at that point.
>
> ...
>
> Comments that start with three semicolons, '`;;;`', should start at the left margin. We use them for comments which should be considered a “heading” by Outline minor mode.
>
> ...
>
> Comments that start with four semicolons, '`;;;;`', should be aligned to the left margin and are used for headings of major sections of a program.

The automatic indentation is done by `electric-indent-mode`. If you wish to disable it entirely, put something like

```
(electric-indent-mode -1)
```

in your init file. You could also disable it for specific modes using something like

```
(electric-indent-local-mode -1)
```

in the appropriate init hooks.

Simply using two semi-colons as suggested by the style guide should also prevent the behaviour, which will let you benefit from `electric-indent-mode` on other code.